# Expected value with multivariate distribution in R

Tags: r, integration

I'm working to calculate the expected value given a multivariate distribution. For example:

```
library(cubature)
library(mvtnorm)

f <- mu <- rep(0, 2)
sig <- diag(2)

adaptIntegrate(
  function(x, f, mu, sigma) {
    ifelse((1+f %*% x) > 0, 
           mvnorm(x, mu, sigma) * log(1+f %*% x), 
           0)
  },
  rep(-100, length(f)), rep(100, length(f)), f, mu, sigma,
  fDim = length(f))
```

However, this integration works really slow. I guess there is much better way to do this job. Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From where `adaptIntegrate` is coming?

Comment: adaptIntegrate is in the [cubature](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cubature) package.

Comment: Yes, it is from the cubature package. The adaptIntegrate seems cannot integrate from -inf to inf. So I used a relative large number instead.

Comment: Where did you get `mvnorm` from?

Comment: do you mean to have `dmvnorm`?

Comment: yes, it's `dmvnorm`, sorry for the typo

Comment: I don't know if this could be solved. But I find that Monte Carlo integration may be a better way to do the multivariate integration. So far it works for me.